# Unexpected Behavior with Swift's Compiler -- Probably

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit, swift-compiler

I was doing a WatchKit app, and I faced a very strange behavior which I think probably hasn't to do with WatchKit, but some weird way the compiler is behaving, although not sure if the compiler is the culprit but that's what I suspect.

The scenario is basically this: The user taps a button on the watch app, the watch app sends a message using `WCSession.default.sendMessage` as follows:

```
    WCSession.default.sendMessage([
        "request": "AmsterdamData",
    ]) { [weak self] (resultDictionary) in
        guard let self = self else {
            return
        }
        // Some implementation
        print("Message Received")
        
    } errorHandler: { (error) in
        print("SessionActivationState", "Error Occurred", error)         
    }
```

Then the iOS app gets the message on `session:didReceiveMessage:` (which I have confirmed is getting called everytime) and sends a message back:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String: Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String: Any]) -> Void) {
    print("didReceiveRequestMessage on iPhone: \(message)")
    guard let request = message["request"] as? String else {
        return
    }
    switch request {
        
    case "AmsterdamData":
        var dataToSend: String? = "hello"
                
        replyHandler([
            "AmsterdamData": dataToSend
        ])
        
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

Ok, this works and I get the message back in the `sendMessage` function's result closure. Good. But the compiler complains and gives me a slight warning of

[image]

Ok, thank you for reminding me. I could easily do that by a `as Any` (which is what XCode recommends me) and makes sense because the warning sounds like this = the expression was "implicitly" coerced from `String?` to `Any`, and we're just making it explicit. Ok, now passing the value like this, so that we can get protected by XCode's yellow shiny sword (metaphor for the big warnings)

```
        replyHandler([
            "AmsterdamData": dataToSend as Any
        ])
```

Even given the messages that Xcode gives, I don't expect this to cause a (big) difference in the logic that actually runs, it would just kinda silence the warning by explicity doing what is already explicit
[image]

Turns out, if I do the `as Any` part, the result closure on the watch app in the `sendMessage` function will not get called, and so doesn't its error closure. Just nothing happens, waiting for its angel of death to kill the process (or not if you have a retain cycle). But, this made me think, is there something I have misunderstood heavily? Is the Xcode message not accurate when it says it's implicitly doing it so let's do it explicitly?

I tried this like 20 times, to make sure it wasn't a connection error or sth. It actually was just because of the `as Any` part, which is very weird.

Comment: Isn’t the problem the Optional?